# Copy multi gitlab variable to file .env in server

Tags: bash, gitlab

this is the script that I copy Gitlab variable to file .env:

```
 - ssh server "echo CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE=$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE >> ./shopping-cart-nestjs/.env"
 - ssh server "echo CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG=$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG >> ./shopping-cart-nestjs/.env"
 - // more script if I have more variable
```

it work well but now if I have multiple gitlab variable I need to write multiple script line. How do I solve this.I search on the Internet and it suggest to use for.
This is my script using for but when read .env it is empty:

```
 - for var in CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG; do
        ssh server "echo $var=\$$var >> ./shopping-cart-nestjs/.env";
      done
 - ssh server "cat ./shopping-cart-nestjs/.env"
 CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE=
 CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG=
```

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: I don't know gitlab, but bash has no idea of a "multiple" variable. Do you  perhaps mean a bash array?

Comment: why do you echo on remote side?

Comment: @KamilCuk, so do not need to echo, right ?

Comment: Consider `CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG=';echo rm /some/dir;'; ssh server "echo CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG=$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG >> ./shopping-cart-nestjs/.env"`. You shouldn't pass unchecked variables to your server to be later re-evaled, this can end bad! Consider researching `eval` security issues, use `printf "%q"` or use  `${var@Q}` bash expansion to quote variables. check scripts with shellcheck. If this is getting complicated, add `.sh` script to the repo, checked with shellcheck and call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run ssh once, why `echo` something already expanded to a file for every var.

```
- for var in CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG; do
     echo "$var=${!var}";
  done | ssh server 'cat > ./shopping-cart-nestjs/.env'
```

Overall, I would rather do:

```
- for var in CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG; do
     echo "$var=${!var}";
  done >tempenv
- scp tempenv server:./shopping-cart-nestjs/.env
```

`${!var}` is *bash* indirect expansion. On POSIX shell you have to use `eval`. Research how to expand a variable by using a name.